# jquery if statement help with supersized plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with the following piece of code, I would like to see if the current image is set, if not display default image instead.

This is my code:

```
jQuery(function($){
            $.supersized({
                slides  :   [ {image : '<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'upload_image', true); ?>' } ]
            });
        });
```

Comment: What is the current image? Where is it? What exactly do you want to check? Your question is too vague. Remember that we don't know the context. The more information you give, the better answers you will get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery(function(){
       var settings = {
                slides  :   [ {image : '<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'upload_image', true); ?>' } ]
            };

       if(!settings.slides[0].image)
          settings.slides[0].image = "setTheDefaultImageHere";

            $.supersized(settings);
        });
```

Comment: @user595600 - Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: it worked, thank you, I was wondering would i be too much to ask to explain this part of the code: settings.slides[0].image?

Comment: settings.slides is an array of json object. so to access the first element of it we used that code and then then image property.